# Proguard - Android App crashes on release version

Tags: android, proguard, release

My App crashing when I create a release build, right after the start.

Logs:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Lkotlin/reflect/KProperty;
    at com.gctech.base.AppContext$Companion.<clinit>(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.gctech.base.AppContext.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
```

Cause :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlin.reflect.KProperty"
```

Proguard rules :

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile, LineNumberTable
```

Comment: kotlin version??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya 1.3.50